# Unable to deploy the project to GAE

Tags: java, google-app-engine

In GAE, I am trying to deploy the project to GAE. I selected the project -> google -> Deploy to AppEngine. It shows a dialog box that says "Project is not an App Engine project". There is no Frontend project selected. What is the mistake i am doing. Any help will be great.

I need to deploy web.xml and appengine.xml to GAE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you have to update with the correct application name in your `appengine-web.xml` file. Update the `<application>` part to the name that you have created in the [Administration Consle](https://appengine.google.com/) and try to redeploy again.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
  <application>_your_app_id_</application>
  <version>1</version>
  <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>
</appengine-web-app>
```

More on how to deal with the `appeninge-web.xml` refer to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig).

Comment: First i would like to thank u for taking time in replying me. I have given right application id. I have checked the appengine-web.xml also. It is correct. wat else could be mistake.

Comment: Try stuff like deploying the hello world app there or create a new application on GAE an try to deploy there (maybe something went wrong with either google or your general setup)

Comment: since the hello world works.. obviously you're doing something wrong... does it run locally without any errors? You'll have to track down what is wrong.. it's going to be really hard to start guessing... there could be tons of stuff that can go sideways.. the fact that the simple app works is a clue :D

Comment: I have successfully deployed the application in GAE. Thanks to all for helping me. I dint not give proper GAE SDK path. That was my mistake.

Comment: @user2919251 Awesome.. have fun with it now :)